# Select cache disks to Storage Spaces Direct

Tags: hyper-v, storage-spaces

I have a 2 clusters nodes with 4 NVMe to cache for 6 SSDs, when a create the storage cluster it does not evenly distribuites equally the cache to drives. So I want to remove one NVMe, so it will distribute equally.

I set the disk usage to retired using `Set-PhysicalDisk -UniqueId xxxx -Usage Retired` but once the server is restarted, the disk backs as Journal.

I also tried to use the `Reset-PhysicalDisk` cmdlet after setting the usage but the results are the same.

If I need to destroy and recreate the pool, there is no problem, this is a test environment for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution, I have to run:

```
$retired = Get-PhysicalDisk -Usage retired
Set-ClusterStorageSpacesDirectDisk -CanBeClaimed:$False -PhysicalDisk $retired[0]
Set-ClusterStorageSpacesDirectDisk -CanBeClaimed:$False -PhysicalDisk $retired[1]
```

Those commands tell to the pool that the specified disks can't be claimed by the pool.